# Sorting by a column in MS Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I am trying to sort a column using VBA in Excel. This is my code,

```
Range("B:B").Sort _
Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

But, It sorts the header column as well. I didn't want the Header Column to be included in the sorting , So I tried the following code,

```
Range("B1:B").Sort _
Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

Which didn't work either. Is there anyway to tell the VBA that my first column is a header name while sorting? Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to the code:

```
Header:=xlYes
```

So it becomes:

```
Range("B:B").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```